# Migration problem: warning message [WARNING] You have 2 available migrations to execute

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Projet Symfony 5.2/PHP 8...

When I do a `make:migration` I get the warning message **`[WARNING] You have 2 available migrations to execute`**.

In my DB I have 5 migrations files saved when I am supposed to have 7, but I do a `doctrine:migrations:migrate` each time and the table creations of my 2 migrations files have been done.

After the warning message, I have the question `Are you sure you wish to continue? (yes/no) [yes]:`
and if I put yes, I get errors like
**`SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'product_category' already exists`**

How is this possible?

Comment: Check this options a) You have created manually this table. b) You have renamed the migration. c) You have more than on migration with product_category creation. My recomendation, drop the database and migrate again.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is solved, I emptied my migration table, deleted all my migrations from my folder and made a new migration